# Regenerating Proxy for WCF Service

Tags: wcf

We are providing WCF services to various clients, one of them is getting the following error. After googled, I found that since client exceeded its idle time, they have to regenerate the proxy again in order to make another call. Now my question, My understanding of this problem is correct? How to make service call withour regenerating the proxy.

The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://Service/Update' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the error message, have you increased the receiveTimeout property for the binding in the configuration file?

Example from msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx):

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISampleService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
```

Comment: I have to ask my service consumer that question. But can we achieve this witout increasing timeout?

Comment: Actually I'd say you have to increase the timeout on the service side, not the consumer side, since it seems the server is closing the connection...

Comment: You have to increase it on both the client and the server.